# Switch case on interface type

Tags: go

I'm trying to identify a type that implements an interface using a `switch`:

```
package main    

import "fmt"


type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return float64(v.X)
}

func do(i interface{}) {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case Abser:
        fmt.Println("theres an Abser")
    case Vertex:
        fmt.Println("theres a Vertex")
    default:
        fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T!\n", v)
    }
}

func main() {
    do(Vertex{1,2})
}
```

This code outputs the value for `Vertex` instead of `Abser`. Ideally it should have output `theres an Abser` since Vertex implements the `Abs()` method. Is it possible to use a switch-case to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not about the switch command, but about pointer receivers.

If you change `func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64` to `func (v Vertex) Abs() float64`, it will give the output `theres an Abser`.

In general code, a type can use its pointer method - you can call `Vertex{1,2}.Abs()`, but what happened behind it is that the Go compiler rewrites it as `(&Vertex{1,2}).Abs()` for you. So `Vertex` does not implement `Abser`.

But on the contrary, a pointer type has all the methods its underlying type has. So even if the API is defined as `func (v Vertex) Abs() float64`, `&Vertex{1,2}` is still an `Abser`. See: https://play.golang.org/p/ONnsjApMywO

See Also:

Method set: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Vertex isn't an Abser, only *Vertex is, if you change your Abs() impl to

```
func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return float64(v.X)
}
```

then Vertex itself is an Abser and your code will print `theres an Abser`